# OnPreferenceChangeListener

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a `EditText` in a preference menu that allows me to edit a URL address. The problem is when I get the preference value in the mainActivity is not getting updated right away after I click OK in the Preference Menu. Not sure how to fix this problem. I tried a bunch of ideas and finally decided to ask.

```
public class PreferencesActivityTest extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.radio_preferences);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferencesActivityTest.this,
                R.xml.radio_preferences, false);
        EditTextPreference editPref =(EditTextPreference)findPreference("MyText");
        editPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
                                    new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                    Object newValue) {
                if (newValue.toString().length() > 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                // If now create a message to the user
                Toast.makeText(PreferencesActivityTest.this,
                        "Invalid Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

PS: This code updates the `newValue` to what I enter in the `EditTextPreference`, doesn't carry the new value to the `MainActivity` until I modify it again...

UPDATE:
In `OnResume()` I can see that the value is updated with the one that I modified in the `PreferenceActivityTest` from `EditTextPreference`. What I'm trying to do is to pass this `newValue` into the `SetDataSource("")`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_radio);
    initializeMediaPlayer();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_edit:
        editURL();
        // make a Dialog or show an Activity
        return true;
    }
}

private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.radio_preferences, false);
    SharedPreferences pref =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String radioPath = pref.getString("MyText", "default value");
    // Toast.makeText(this, radioPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
        radioPlayer.reset();
        // radioPlayer.setDataSource("http://31.xx.xxx");
        // Toast.makeText(this, radioPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        radioPlayer.setDataSource(radioPath);
    } catch {
    }
}

public void editURL() {
    stopPlaying();
    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), PreferencesActivityTest.class));
}
```

I am doing something fundamentally wrong but I need help. Thank you in advance !

Comment: how are you calling the preference activity? If you are calling it directly, you probably need to change the call to onActivityForResult so you refresh your data once you return from the Activity.

Comment: Thx DigCamara, I will try it tonight.

Comment: I tried it last night but I did not succeeded in making it work properly. Thanks for your help/time. :)

Comment: Is that your code? You're still calling startActivity. You need to call startActivityForResult instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how are you calling the preference activity? If you are calling it directly, you probably need to change the call to [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) so you refresh your data once you return from the Activity

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you so much. Was not paying attention that's why it didn't work initially :). I can go sleep now feeling very accomplished !!!